# Vuex Store state is missing value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, store

Good evening, I am developing a store with vuex where I manage the login procedure; when the procedure is successful I should register a TokenSession and a role in the state.

Once the correct credentials have been entered, the user accesses the home page and the status data is set correctly;
I currently protect the various sections of the site with a beforEnter in the router.js file to verify that the user is authenticated and is an administrator.

But every time I move to a section the state of the store loses all the data, or rather returns to the initial state, as if no mutation has occurred; what could be the problem?

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
import router from './router'

Vue.use(Vuex)


export default new Vuex.Store({
   state : {
        idToken:'',
        role:'',
    },

    mutations:{

        authUser(state, accesso){
            state.idToken=accesso.token;
            state.role=accesso.role;
        },

        logout(state){
            state.idToken = '';
            state.role = '';
        },
        },

    actions: {
        login({commit,state}, authData) {

                axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/login', authData )
                    .then(res => {
                        let accesso = res.data
                       
                        let token = accesso.token
                        let role = accesso.role
                        console.log("role(dopo if):" + role)
                        if ( token !=null) {
                            localStorage.setItem('token', token)
                           
                            commit('authUser',accesso)
                            console.log("state dopo commit: " + state.role);
                            router.push("/home")

                        } else
                            {
                            alert('USERNAME O PASSWORD ERRATI')
                        }
                    }).catch(err => console.log(err))

        },
        logout({commit}){
                commit('logout')
                localStorage.removeItem('token')
                resolve()
            }

    },
    getters : {
        isAuthenticated: state => !!state.idToken,
        role: state => state.role,
        }
})
```

the router.js file is:

```
import Home from './components/Home.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Dipendenti from './components/dipendenti/Dipendenti.vue'
import Login from './components/Login'
import ErrPage from './components/errPage.vue'
import store from './store'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

 const routes=[
     //pagina iniziale, visualizzo sempre la login per prima
    {path: '', component: Login},

     //pagina home contenente il calendario, tutti i loggati possono accedervi, solo admin può modificare
    {path: '/home', component: Home,
        beforeEnter:(to,from, next)=>{
        if(store.getters.isAuthenticated){ next() }
        else{ next('/login') }
        }},

     //pagina della Login
    {path: '/errPage', component: Login},

     //pagina con elenco dei dipendenti,  accesso alla pagina solo loggato e solo admin
    {path: '/dipendenti', component: Dipendenti,
        
        beforeEnter:(to,from, next)=>{

            if(store.getters.isAuthenticated==true && store.getters.role=="admin"){ next() }
            else{ next('/errPage') }
        }}]
export default new VueRouter({mode: 'history', routes})
```

Comment: When you navigate to a new page does it load via Ajax or do a full page load?

Comment: the sections of the site should be loaded from the <router-view> of the App.vue page, but with each movement the page reloads completely

Comment: That's probably why your store is resetting after each navigation, if you can fix that issue then it should allow the store to persist between pages.

Comment: the problem is that I can't fix the page reload, how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you add an example of how you are including your page links?